# An integer $k$ is a generator of group $\mathbb{Z_n}$ if and only if $\gcd(k, n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

An integer $k$ is a generator of the group $\mathbb{Z_n}$ if and only if $\gcd(k, n)=1$.

So $\langle k\rangle=\mathbb{Z_n}$ iff $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Is there any general way to prove this?

I see that it's so obvious but can't find a general way to prove it.

Comment: Hint: $\text{gcd}(k, n) = 1$ if and only if there exist integers $a, b$ such that $ak + bn = 1$ (this is also interesting to prove if you've never seen it).

Comment: Please give your definition of "generator of $\Bbb Z_n$" (and is that a group or ring?)

Comment: oh it's a group. sorry!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk  easier, and preferable to use `\gcd(k, n) = 1`

Comment: @amWhy what's the difference?

Comment: Spacing.  And as $\gcd$ is an operator, it makes sense it displays as such.  Unfortunately, there are some operators. like lcd, which one needs to use `\operatorname{lcd}`

Comment: @amwhy thanks! I just forgot that was already defined.

Comment: No problem, @diracdeltafunk.  I learned a lot about mathjax usage by tips from other users in my first year or two here.  Anytime I can offer a tip that saves the author/commenter a little time when formatting, I try to return the favor!

Comment: Same as the linked dupes except you have additive notation, so a power $a^k$ of a generator $\,a\,$ becomes an integer multiple $\,k\cdot a\ (=k\,$ here using $\,a=1\,$ to generate the additive group $\, Z_n).\,$  This is a FAQ with likely many tens if not hundreds of answers. Please strive to search for answers *before* posting questions.

Comment: @amWhy just a reminder that you can use `\rm` for `\operatorname`.

Answer (score 0):

By Bezout, the integer has an inverse $\bmod n$ precisely when $(n,k)=1$.

But, $1$ generates $\Bbb Z_n$.  So once you can get $1$ it's all over.

Comment: Could you elaborate out what this mean? :the integer has an inverse $\mod n$ precisely when $(n,k)=1$.

Comment: Sure. By Bezout there exist $x,y$ such that $nx+ky=1$. This says precisely that $y=k^{-1}\bmod n$.

Comment: Sometimes we express this by saying $k$ is a 'unit' $\bmod n$.

Comment: oh I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If $\gcd(n,k)=d > 1$, then $k/d$ is an integer, so
$$n . \frac{k}{d} = 0 \in \mathbb{Z}_n$$

so the order of $k$ is less than $n/d$, so it is striclty less than $n$, so $k$ does not generate $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

If $\gcd(n,k)=1$, then there exists $a,b$ such that $ak+bn=1$, so
$$ak=1 \in \mathbb{Z}_n$$

so the subgroup generated by $k$ contains $1$, which generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$, so it contains $\mathbb{Z}_n$, so it is $\mathbb{Z}_n$.